# input pattern attribute dose not seem to accept a regexp warped with (/regexp/)

Tags: regex, angular, html, typescript

i have this working input validation

```
<input class="form-control" pattern="^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,12}$" placeholder="" type="password" required>
```

i am trying to store the pattern in `passwordPattern` variable and inject it to the html

```
    import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
    @Component({
      selector: 'my-component',
      templateUrl: './my-component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./my-component.scss']
    })
    export class myComponent implements OnInit {
    passwordPattern:RegExp;
     constructor() {
// 1 digit, 1 letter, minimum 8 chars and maximum 12 chars
      this.passwordPattern = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,12}$/ ;
      }

    ngOnInit() {}

    }
```

html

```
   <input class="form-control" [pattern]="passwordPattern" placeholder="" type="password" required>
```

the input pattern attribute dose not seem to accept a regexp warped with / / (/regexp/). 
i tried to remove it and to wrap it as a string but it is not working (`this.passwordPattern = '^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,12}$';`), i also tried to add the pattern using the `new RegExp()` (`this.passwordPattern = new RegExp("(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,12}")`) did not work as well, looking for the right way to do this,my goal is to have this pattern as a global variable throw out the app. any help would be appreciated.

see an example here https://jsfiddle.net/1hk7knwq/10565/

Comment: What do you mean by "i tried to remove it and to wrap it as a string"? Can you show us what you did?

Comment: Like `this.passwordPattern = "^(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,12}$";`?

Comment: i updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Please modify your class variable value as:

```
this.passwordPattern = new RegExp("(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{8,12}") ;
```

Now you will be using a RegExp constructor to create a regular expression object for matching text with a pattern. This will work.